# hide div tag in jsp forloop based on condition

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am working on jsp for loops.I have a requirement where I loop the list and display the data for each iteration..I have html div tag with class name to display all the data for each iteration.  however, if one of the condition is met in that loop I should not display that particular data. When I tried to hide through .className.hide() it is hiding all the div data in the previous iterations. 
Sample code
`

```
<s:iterator value="dispDomainList" var="curDomain">
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${dFlags.AFlag == 'false'}">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pClass).hide();
});
</c:when>
</c:choose>

<c:choose>
<c:when test="${dFlags.BFlag == 'false'}">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pClass).hide();
});
</c:when>
</c:choose>
<div class="col-lg-12 pClass>
DATA HERE 
</div>
</s:iterator>
```

`

if my dFlags.AFlag is true then it shoudld display data. Now if dFlags.BFlag is false, it hides the whole data from dFlags.AFlag condition too. help me out here.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: please post some codes, did you try to render = "false" on your jsp tag?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pClass).hide();
```

will hide the whole div where you expect your data to be displayed. You do not really need jQuery to hide/show data in the loop as you already use JSTL tags. Just use

```
<c:if test="${dFlags.AFlag == 'true'}">
<!-- display data -->
</c:if>
<c:if test="${dFlags.BFlag == 'false'}">
<!-- do nothing -->
</c:if>
```

Comment: Got it. I thought of doing that way, but If BFlag is true then I need to include the similar type of data that in the second if loop to show it(data populated through for loop). Can't I make the display data code common for both AFlag and BFlag so that I can show/hide based on condition to avoid code redundancy?

Comment: Thanks. I am able to figure it out. I placed my code in external file and included that file whenever my condition is met.

Comment: @abhilash It's great  to hear you figured it out yourself, although it was not mandatory to use external files to achieve this as you can put the code of the external files inside the corresponding JSTL conditions on your .jsp, but if that did the trick .. :)